# Appending two data sources in a data flow task

Tags: sql, ssis

I am fairly new to SSIS, so i apologize if this is a novice question. I am bringing in two different sets of data, after which i want to APPEND, then send the combined table to a SQL server database table. How do i setup the APPEND portion? Bringing the data in and sending out is not a problem as i've done it before in other packages, but i'm stuck when trying to append.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, found the UNION ALL tool.